# Render Video as png with Alpha

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, alpha-channel, photoshop-cs6

I have pixel art that I want to put in an animated png. I animated it in the timeline, but when I rendered it into a series of pngs, It has no partial transparency. Anyone know how to solve this?